# Wordpress: On jQuery button click preselect option in Contact Form 7 menu

Tags: contact-form, contact-form-7

I have a Wordpress site, where is a page with many items. When user clicks on item he wants, page will open. In this page there is a button "Contact". The thing I want to achieve is that when user hits the contact button, opens next page with the form and the select menu is preselected depending on the email on this item page. Can someone please help me with this?

Here is some parts of single post page, where is the button for the click to go to the form page:

```
<button class="btn">
 <span>Contact</span>
</button>
```

This page has a lot of information where is also mentioned email address for this specific item of this page:

```
<p class="email">Email: <a href="mailto:<?php the_field('contact_email'); ?>">
 <?php the_field('contact_email'); ?>
</a></p>
```

Here is my Contact Form 7 code:

```
<div class="contact-form">
<div class="form-group">
  [text* your-name class:form-control placeholder "Name"] 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  [text* your-name class:form-control placeholder "Company"] 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  [email* your-email class:form-control placeholder "Email"] 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  [select* menu-105 class:form-control "Office 1|email1@example.com" "Office 2|email2@example.com" "Office 3|email3@example.com" "Office 4|email4@example.com"]
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  [text your-subject class:form-control placeholder "Subject"] 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  [textarea your-message x3 class:form-control placeholder "Message"] 
</div>
<div class="form-group form-check">
 [acceptance acceptance-955 optional] By ticking this box you agree to this information here in <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">privacy policy</a>.[/acceptance]
</div>
<div class="btn-container-right">
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  [submit "Send" class:btn-sm]
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The thing I want to achieve is that when user hits the contact button, opens next page with the form and the select menu is preselected depending on the email on this item page. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You can do this with jQuery.  If you post some code... you can get some help with that.

Comment: @HowardE thanks! I will asap!

Comment: @HowardE I added details. I hope this is enough.

Comment: It's still somewhat unclear as to what you want to achieve.  The button in the first block is a link to another page, where the email address in the second block is the email to be sent to?  You want that to be the recipient of the CF7 form?

Comment: @HowardE The contact button is on the same page where all the information about that item is and also email address, just mentioned in the text as a link. But when user decides to press the contact button, he will go Contact page where is the form with these fields and also one with the select menu and in this select menu I want the email address to be preselected, depending on the previous page information (email that is there in the description). Does this makes more understandable?

Comment: So if the first page, the user clicks on 'office1' on the form the select  ` [select* menu-105 class:form-control "Office 1|email1@example.com" "Office 2|email2@example.com" "Office 3|email3@example.com" "Office 4|email4@example.com"]` will have office 1 selected?

Comment: @HowardE Here I made a quick wireframe to show the situation and what I need. Please see the image: https://i.ibb.co/g7fkTKF/Screen-Shot-2020-02-20-at-13-13-11.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... so first, you want to pass a URL parameter to the contact form from the button.

So your updated link is, (where you're urlecoding the space as %20)

`yourdomain.com/contact-form/?email=office%201`

Then add this script to your theme .js files or wherever you can.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.urlParam = function (name) {
        var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)')
                          .exec(window.location.search);

        return (results !== null) ? results[1] || 0 : false;
    }
    // Since above function returns false if blank, check if email $_GET param is entered
    if ( false !== $.urlParam('email')){
        $('select[name="your-email"]').val(decodeURIComponent($.urlParam('email')))
            .change(); // set select name to the name of your form field in CF7
    }
});
```

the `decodeURIComponent` is only if you're using a URL Encoded parameter... This is because you have a space in your selections "Office 1", "Office 2"

set the [name=] to the name of your CF7 field.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort! I added this to my code - when entering the contact page, it shows the select field without anything and the value can be selected only from dropdown. Here is my code:

 <a href="http://local/contact/?email=<?php the_field('contact_email'); ?>">
<button class="btn-sm">
<span>Contact</span>
</button>
</a>

And in js changed this line: $('select[name="menu-105"]')

What can cause this? Maybe because I need the option value to be preselected instead of email address?

Comment: what is returned by the_field('contact_email') ? the email address??  `Maybe because I need the option value to be preselected instead of email address? ` Yes.. My code will work as long as you're passing the values of the select in the URL parameter.

Comment: Yes, works like a charm! I will try to make this somehow work to show in the select the option value instead of email.

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot! :)